# jQuery. Append() не копирует data объекта

Tags: jquery, append

Простой [пример](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/wKMjzJ):

HTML:

```
<div id="con"></div> 
<button id="but">Add</button>
<button id="but2">Show</button>
```

Вот код:

```
function appendBlock() {
  b = $("<div class='row'>r</div>");
  $.data(b, "test", 2);
  console.log( $.data(b, "test"));
  $("#con").append(b);
  $("#con").append(b); //2
}
$( document ).ready(function() {
  $("#but").click(function () {appendBlock()});
  $("#but2").click(function(){alert(  $(".row").data("test"))});
});
```

Ожидание:

1. Два добавленный блока после нажатия, а не один
2. Сохраненная data у добавленных блоков.

Как провернуть?

Comment: а где тут `#con` ?

Comment: А причем тут сохранение `data` ? Оно как-раз отлично работает: http://jsfiddle.net/qrou0tvc/ выводит в консоли `2`

Comment: @SaidolimDjuraev по ссылке на codepen
Там простой блок:
`<div id="con"></div>
<button id="but">Add</button>`

Comment: @DmitriySimushev в примере выводится data добавляемого элемента. Если потом посмотреть data($("#con .row"), "test"), ничего не увидим

Comment: @DTXqueque, что-то мне подсказывает, что codepen требует авторизации для просмотра снипета. У меня тоже нет никакого блока `#con`

Comment: @DmitriySimushev забыл форкнуть. Исправил и в вопросе
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/wKMjzJ

Comment: @DTXqueque, добавьте, пожалуйста, в вопрос пример того, как вы пытаетесь получить данные.

Comment: @DmitriySimushev в новом примере уже есть:
 $("#but2").click(function(){alert($.data($(".row")[0], "test"))});

Comment: @DTXqueque, минимальный и достаточный пример для воспроизведения ошибки должен быть **в самом вопросе**. Внешние ссылки могут служить только дополнением.

Comment: @DmitriySimushev Исправил

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для вставки несколько раз вы можете использовать метод `.clone()` и установить параметр метода `withDataAndEvents` в `true`, это даст возможность скопировать так же data и events объекта (https://api.jquery.com/clone/#clone-withDataAndEvents). Далее остается только выбрать желаемое.

Обратите внимание что при вызове `$(".row")[0]` вы получаете строку (html код) а не обьект, что не дает возможности что либо получить.

```
function appendBlock() {
  b = $("<div class='row'>r</div>").data("test", 2);
  console.log( b.data("test"));
  $("#con").append(b.clone(true));
  $("#con").append(b.clone(true)); //2
}
$( document ).ready(function() {
  $("#but").click(function () {appendBlock()});
  $("#but2").click(function(){
    console.log($(".row:eq(1)").data("test"));
  });
});
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/qObYqG

Answer (score 0):

Ваш вопрос состоит из двух частей, поэтому и отвечать буду по порядку.

> 1) Два добавленный блока после нажатия, а не один

При повторном вызове `.append(b)` узел `b` сначала удаляется из документа, а потом добавляется в то же место. Это связано с тем, что один и тот же узел не может быть находится в двух точках дерева DOM одновременно (это просто не имеет смысла).

Если вы хотите вставить два *одинаковых* узла, вы можете клонировать узел перед вставкой, например так:

```
$('#con').append(b);
$('#con').append(b.clone());
```

> 2) Сохраненная data у добавленных блоков.

А с данными все нормально. Они отлично добавляются. А вот с выборкой действительно проблемы. Похоже, что проблема в том, что первый аргумент `$.data` в функции `appendBlock` это не тоже самое что `$(".row")[0]` при попытке получения данных. Как бы то ни было, я бы рекомендовал использовать использовать метод `.data` на узле вместо `$.data`:

```
var b = $("<div class='row'>r</div>");
b.data('test', 2);
// ...
$('#con .row').first().data('test'); // Выведет 2 для ПЕРВОГО найденного div.
```

Таким образом весь ваш код может выглядеть как-то так:

```
function appendBlock() {
    b = $('<div class="row">r</div>');
    b.data('test', 2);
    $('#con').append(b);
    $('#con').append(b.clone(true));
}

$('#but').click(function () {
    appendBlock();
});

$('#data').click(function() {
    alert($('#con .row').first().data('test'));
});
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/83mwey1x/)

**UPD:**

При клонировании, для копирования `data` свойств нужно передвать `true` в качестве первого параметра метода `.clone` (см. https://api.jquery.com/clone/#clone-withDataAndEvents).

Answer (score 0):

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/XmXqRy

```js
function appendBlock() {
  b = $("<div class='row'>r</div>");
  b.data('test', 2);
  console.log(b.data('test'));
  $(b).add(b.clone()).appendTo('#con');
}
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#but").click(appendBlock);
  $("#but2").click(function() {
    alert($(document).find(".row").eq(0).data('test'))
  });
});
```

```html
<div id="con"></div>
<button id="but">Add</button>
<button id="but2">Show</button>
```

Привет, первая проблема в том, что элемент был уже вставлен и коллекция, записанная в переменную b была изменена. Вторая проблема в том что метод `$.data` хоть и выполняет практически то что тебе нужно, но он работает на более глубоком уровне и не попадает в коллекцию jQuery при выборке элементов. Вместо этого стоит использовать `$('element').data('test')`.